# Some problems after new project in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, new-project

After creating a new project in Eclipse on Windows 8 I face this problem and I'll have to restart Eclipse to fix it.

> Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130772027 Failed to
>   find the style corresponding to the id 2130771996
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Exception details are logged in Window
>   > Show View > Error Log
>
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log) See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more
>   details.`

Please help me with this issue, it's so annoying.

Comment: use Android Studio! if you don't have any special reason to use Eclipse, Android Studio will help you a lot on Android development: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Android Studio is very slow and it will slow down my progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import "android-support-v7-appcompat" library in your work space and then add it to project use following step.

- right click on project click on property.
- select android from right side.
- then click on add and select android-support-v7-appcompat and click apply and ok.

that's it